# Sankey Diagram highchart Issue

Tags: highcharts, angular6

I want to generate a Sankey Diagram like below , as of now I am using data for series like this:

```
 keys: ['from', 'to' ,'weight'],
        data: [
        ['Entrance  A', 'Platform 1' , 10 ],
        ['Entrance  A', 'Platform 2' , 2 ],
        ['Entrance B', 'Platform 2' , 3 ],
        ['Entrance C', 'Platform 3' , 5 ],
        ['Entrance D', 'Platform 4' , 7 ],
        ['Entrance E', 'Platform 1' , 6 ],
        ['Entrance F', 'Platform 2' , 10 ],
        ['Entrance F', 'Platform 4' , 4 ],
        ['Entrance G', 'Platform 1' , 13 ],
        ['Platform 1', 'Exit F' , 9 ],
        ['Platform 2', 'Exit D' , 10 ],
        ['Platform 2', 'Exit F' , 4 ],
        ['Platform 3', 'Exit G' , 5 ],
        ['Platform 3', 'Exit B' , 11 ],
        ['Platform 4', 'Exit C' , 5 ],
        ['Platform 4', 'Exit E' , 6]
        ]
```

but this generate three node diagram 
[image]

What kind of data should I use to get similar kind of graph as given in image 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the platforms, you can create two types of node : 'Platform X from' and 'Platform X to'. Then, you can use the `nodes` section to re-define them so both have the same name and same color :

```
series: [{
    type: 'sankey',
    keys: ['from', 'to' ,'weight'],
    data: [
        ['Entrance A', 'Platform 1 to' , 10 ],
        ['Entrance A', 'Platform 2 to' , 2 ],
        ['Entrance B', 'Platform 2 to' , 3 ],
        ['Entrance C', 'Platform 3 to' , 5 ],
        ['Entrance D', 'Platform 4 to' , 7 ],
        ['Entrance E', 'Platform 1 to' , 6 ],
        ['Entrance F', 'Platform 2 to' , 10 ],
        ['Entrance F', 'Platform 4 to' , 4 ],
        ['Entrance G', 'Platform 1 to' , 13 ],
        ['Platform 1 from', 'Exit F' , 9 ],
        ['Platform 2 from', 'Exit D' , 10 ],
        ['Platform 2 from', 'Exit F' , 4 ],
        ['Platform 3 from', 'Exit G' , 5 ],
        ['Platform 3 from', 'Exit B' , 11 ],
        ['Platform 4 from', 'Exit C' , 5 ],
        ['Platform 4 from', 'Exit E' , 6]
    ],
    nodes: [
        {id: 'Platform 1 from', 'name': 'Platform 1', colorIndex: 0},
        {id: 'Platform 1 to',   'name': 'Platform 1', colorIndex: 0},

        {id: 'Platform 2 from', 'name': 'Platform 2', colorIndex: 1},
        {id: 'Platform 2 to',   'name': 'Platform 2', colorIndex: 1},

        {id: 'Platform 3 from', 'name': 'Platform 3', colorIndex: 2},
        {id: 'Platform 3 to',   'name': 'Platform 3', colorIndex: 2},

        {id: 'Platform 4 from', 'name': 'Platform 4', colorIndex: 3},
        {id: 'Platform 4 to',   'name': 'Platform 4', colorIndex: 3},
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks Joffery , one more doubt the 'to' option of the array sequence is not as per the diagram how can we achieve that.

Comment: In the node section, you can add a `index` to fix the order (e.g. `{id: 'Platform 1 to', 'name': 'Platform 1', colorIndex: 0, index: 0}`). Node with index 0 will be on top, index = 1 just below, ... But you need to have all your nodes (Entrance, Platform, Exit) in the nodes section, not just the platform ones.